# Store multiple dynamic form into object and post and upload using jquery post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, dynamic

I have a dynamic form which will create when user enter a number in form 1 when user press tab or go to next tab, It will create a dynamic form below form 1 which user can enter data and date and also attach a file.

Each Time user enter a number in form 1 and press tab there will be a dynamic form 2 below form 1 and user can enter data and it should be hold until all of form 1 fields completed by user with their form 2 attachments data.

I've managed to Create it's dynamic process using jquery but the problem I'm facing is I can not hold this dynamic forms data and as you can see I've tried to grab arrays data but they're empty when I view check using console.

I want to hold this data this way : form 1 : textfield 1 -> hasmany -> form 2 (textfield, date, file) 
and then post this data to php file to save and upload files.

any idea or solution how to accomplish this ?

Jquery part :

```
$(function () {

    $('#general').change(function () {
        extracted('general', 'general : ');
    });

    $('#in_uni_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_uni_level', 'in uni level : ');
    });

    $('#in_section_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_section_level', 'in section level : ');
    });

    $('#in_country_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_country_level', 'in country level :‌ ');
    });

    function extracted(selection, Gtitle) {

        var brief = [];
        var contributor = [];
        var datepick = [];
        var file = [];
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=brief]').each(function () {
            brief.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=contributor]').each(function () {
            contributor.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=datepick]').each(function () {
            datepick.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=file]').each(function () {
            file.push(this.value);
        });
        console.log(brief, contributor, datepick, file);
        //                $("#dynamic_table").empty();//clear dynamic table data each time focus change

        console.log($('#' + selection).val());

        var count = $('#' + selection).val();
        if (count > 0) {

            var nextStep = $(document.createElement('tbody'));

            var Dynamic_form_header =
                '<tr>' +
                '<th>' + Gtitle + '</th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th>Short Brief</th>' +
                '<th>Contributers count</th>' +
                '<th>date</th>' +
                '<th>Related doc</th>' +
                '</tr>';

            var Dynamic_form_body = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Dynamic_form_body +=
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="brief[]" id="brief" ' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="contributor[]" id="contributor"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="datepick[]" class="datepicker"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="file" name="file[]" id="doc"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            }
            nextStep.html(Dynamic_form_header + Dynamic_form_body);

            nextStep.appendTo("#dynamic_table");
        }

        // default
        $('#dynamic_table').live('click', function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

        });
    }



        $("#Submit_form").click(function () {

            $.post("Requests/spc.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                    Save_Form: true,
                    brief: brief,
                    contributor: contributor,
                    datepick: datepick,
                    file: file,
                },
                function (response) {  // Required Callback Function
                    //======== disable loading for onclick event ==========
                    $("#loading_gif").hide();
                    $("#add_user_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
                    //======== disable loading for onclick event ==========

                    //$("#Response").text(response);
                    if (response == "save") {
                        $("#Response").text("ارسال دعوتنامه  با موفقیت صورت گرفت.").css({color: 'green'});
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

Html Section :

```
<form id="form" method="post" action=""
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' width="360"
           border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="general">general</label>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="in_uni_level">in uni level</label>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="in_section_level">in section level</label>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="in_country_level">in country level</label>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="general" 
                       name="general"/>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <input type="text" id="in_uni_level"
                       name="in_uni_level"/>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <input type="text" id="in_section_level"
                       name="in_section_level"/>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <input type="text" id="in_country_level"
                       name="in_country_level"/>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="cleaner h30"></div>

    <table class='styled-table' id="dynamic_table"
           cellspacing='0' width="500" border='1'>

    </table>

</form>

<button id="Submit_form">Submit</button>
```

Snapshot : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were having is that you were not calling a `change` function on the second form for each field so it could capture the data to push it into the array. I changed your code a little, but seems to be doing what you want. I also added a fiddle.

Also you may not want to `push` the value every time on `change` because what if the user goes back a edits the field. It would add it to the array instead of replacing it.

You also are going to have to deal with some multidimensional arrays here as well which you did not implement because if a user selects more than 1 in the first form you will have to store x amount of arrays to associate with the original request.

```
$(function () {

  var brief = [];
  var contributor = [];
  var datepick = [];
  var file = [];

    $('#general').change(function () {
        extracted('general', 'general : ');
    });

    $('#in_uni_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_uni_level', 'in uni level : ');
    });

    $('#in_section_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_section_level', 'in section level : ');
    });

    $('#in_country_level').change(function () {
        extracted('in_country_level', 'in country level : ');
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#brief', function () {
        brief.push(this.value);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#contributor', function () {
        contributor.push(this.value);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#datepick', function () {
        datepick.push(this.value);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#file', function () {
        file.push(this.value);
    });

    function extracted(selection, Gtitle) {

        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=brief]').each(function () {
            brief.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=contributor]').each(function () {
            contributor.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=datepick]').each(function () {
            datepick.push(this.value);
        });
        $('#dynamic_table').find('[name=file]').each(function () {
            file.push(this.value);
        });
        console.log(brief, contributor, datepick, file);
        //                $("#dynamic_table").empty();//clear dynamic table data each time focus change

        console.log($('#' + selection).val());

        var count = $('#' + selection).val();
        if (count > 0) {

            var nextStep = $(document.createElement('tbody'));

            var Dynamic_form_header =
                '<tr>' +
                '<th>' + Gtitle + '</th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '<th></th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th>Short Brief</th>' +
                '<th>Contributers count</th>' +
                '<th>date</th>' +
                '<th>Related doc</th>' +
                '</tr>';

            var Dynamic_form_body = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Dynamic_form_body +=
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="brief[]" id="brief" ' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="contributor[]" id="contributor"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" name="datepick[]" class="datepicker"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="file" name="file[]" id="doc"' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            }
            nextStep.html(Dynamic_form_header + Dynamic_form_body);

            nextStep.appendTo("#dynamic_table");
        }

        // default
        $('#dynamic_table').on('click', function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqrbsgs8/

Comment: Thanks for response I want to get the data on submit button which I didn't put in the form yet, so the problem of multidimentional arrays will go away i think

Comment: finish your code and edit the question so we can see it all

Comment: I get error for the part you added to my code :Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function